# PHP switch case Url

Tags: php

I want to make my link ex:

- www.bestproducts.com/products.php to
- www.bestproducts.com/?products or
- www.bestproducts.com/?page=products. So how can I do it?

Comment: Can you give more examples of what you have tried? .htaccess?

Comment: What's the purpose ? Why you want that ? just curious ... ;)

Comment: I am not sure what you want? Do you want to load dynamic pages? Cause thats pretty simple

Comment: the / you can always think away when you try to load dynamic pages. It makes no sense. The / just says its in a folder deeper. so loading dynamycly doesnt make sense. it would be then bestproducts.com?page=products.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to have pretty urls. Then you can use `htaccess`. [More info about pretty urls](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/). (you have to create additional urls in the `htaccess` for the page arguments)

Answer (score 0):

How you can do your task:

```
$url = 'www.bestproducts.com/products.php';

$url_array = explode('/', $url);

$result_url1 = implode('/?', $url_array);

$result_url2 = implode('/?page=', $url_array);
```

Comment: What if there are more than one `/`s in the URL ?

Comment: @Dev I've only answered one certain question. "I want to make my link ex:". This is the way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example for the botom one. I did it for my page as well, however, instead of page=products, i have just adressed a single value you to it, in my case: p

the link is then index.php?p=members

Bassically what happens in here that my script checks what i give the to the value p. let me show you in a code

html:

```
 <a href="index.php?p=members" title="Members">Members</a>
```

I request the link p=members to be dynamically loaded in my hyperlink. What runs in my content area is a script that looks for that.

```
<?php
     if (!empty($_GET['p'])){
        $pages_dir = 'inc/content';
        $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
        unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

        $p = $_GET['p'];

        if(in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)){
            include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');  
            }
                else
            {
                echo 'Sorry, page not found';
            }
        }
    else
        {
             include($pages_dir.'/home.inc.php');
        }
?>
```

To spill it out, the if statement checks request the p value out of the hyperlink (remember i said in the html p=members?) i create a variable that checks the folder inc/content which contain my content pages. that variable contains an array with the names of the pages (the unset part is that it removes the . and .. within a folder) It creates an array. Then i let it run through another if else statement. This tells to look for the file name (members) with the taggs inc.php (the inc part is not needed, but i did it so it was clear that file was an include). If it is in the array, include it, if not, it tells me page not found. If there is no value in p (to close it) it basically opens my index page.

I hope this helps